# Problem in exporting a plot with background to pdf

Tags: export

Just wondering if someone could help me for this problem. I have utilised `prolog` to use a jpg image as the background of my plot in order to compare my results with a reference plot. 
Although the outcome looks very good in the Mathematica working environment, when I try to export the outcome to pdf the scaling of the background image will be changed and the exported pdf graph is not like what I can see in the Mathematica working environment.

This is what I used to draw the plot:

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"];
backimage = Import["backimage.jpg"];
ListLinePlot[{Data1}, Mesh -> Full, InterpolationOrder -> 3, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Darker[Blue, 0.5]}}, Joined -> {True}, PlotMarkers -> {{"*",18}}, PlotRange -> {{320, 480}, {-80/1000, 80/1000}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, FrameTicks -> Automatic, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.0035], Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 16],  GridLines -> None, AxesStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.0035], Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], Prolog -> {Texture[backimage], Polygon[{Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}], Scaled[{0, 1}]}, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}]
```

where data points are:

```
Data1={{320.`, 0.00171`}, {320.625`, 0.00802`}, {321.25`,  0.01382`}, {321.875`, 0.0194`}, {322.5`, 0.02464`}, {323.125`, 0.02974`}, {323.75`, 0.03426`}, {324.375`, 0.03881`}, {325.`, 0.04315`}, {325.625`, 0.04729`}, {326.25`, 0.051`}, {326.875`, 0.05469`}, {327.5`, 0.05792`}, {328.125`, 0.06066`}, {328.75`,0.06287`}, {329.375`, 0.06448`}, {330.`, 0.06512`}, {330.625`,0.065`}, {331.25`, 0.06418`}, {331.875`, 0.06236`}, {332.5`, 0.05963`}, {333.125`, 0.0562`}, {333.75`, 0.05219`}, {334.375`, 0.0474`}, {335.`, 0.04238`}, {335.625`, 0.037`}, {336.25`, 0.03139`}, {336.875`, 0.02559`}, {337.5`, 0.02011`}, {338.125`,  0.01444`}, {338.75`, 0.0088`}, {339.375`, 0.00313`}, {340.`, -0.00233`}, {340.625`, -0.00813`}, {341.25`, -0.01374`}, {341.875`, -0.01949`}, {342.5`, -0.02523`}, {343.125`, -0.03118`}, {343.75`, -0.03665`}, {344.375`, -0.04212`}, {345.`,-0.04726`}, {345.625`, -0.05204`}, {346.25`, -0.05601`}, {346.875`,-0.05954`}, {347.5`, -0.06211`}, {348.125`, -0.0638`}, {348.75`,-0.06465`}, {349.375`, -0.06484`}, {350.`, -0.06399`}, {350.625`,-0.06246`}, {351.25`, -0.06044`}, {351.875`, -0.05791`}, {352.5`,-0.05485`}, {353.125`, -0.05157`}, {353.75`, -0.048`}, {354.375`,-0.044`}, {355.`, -0.03988`}, {355.625`, -0.03559`}, {356.25`,-0.03091`}, {356.875`, -0.02575`}, {357.5`, -0.02044`}, {358.125`,-0.01462`}, {358.75`, -0.00845`}, {359.375`, -0.00192`}, {360.`,   0.00468`}, {360.625`, 0.01172`}, {361.25`, 0.01853`}, {361.875`, 0.02515`}, {362.5`, 0.03135`}, {363.125`, 0.03737`}, {363.75`, 0.04252`}, {364.375`, 0.04719`}, {365.`, 0.05109`}, {365.625`, 0.05436`}, {366.25`, 0.05672`}, {366.875`, 0.0588`}, {367.5`,  0.06019`}, {368.125`, 0.06105`}, {368.75`, 0.06141`}, {369.375`,   0.06165`}, {370.`, 0.06134`}, {370.625`, 0.06071`}, {371.25`, 0.05967`}, {371.875`, 0.0581`}, {372.5`, 0.05576`}, {373.125`, 0.05296`}, {373.75`, 0.04948`}, {374.375`, 0.04515`}, {375.`, 0.04011`}, {375.625`, 0.03457`}, {376.25`, 0.02845`}, {376.875`, 0.02188`}, {377.5`, 0.01525`}, {378.125`, 0.00844`}, {378.75`, 0.0016`}, {379.375`, -0.005`}, {380.`, -0.01107`}, {380.625`,-0.01703`}, {381.25`, -0.02254`}, {381.875`, -0.02772`}, {382.5`, -0.03252`}, {383.125`, -0.03728`}, {383.75`, -0.04152`}, {384.375`, -0.04573`}, {385.`, -0.04976`}, {385.625`, -0.05364`}, {386.25`, -0.05688`}, {386.875`, -0.05991`}, {387.5`, -0.06228`}, {388.125`, -0.06402`}, {388.75`, -0.06492`}, {389.375`, -0.0652`}, {390.`, -0.06431`}, {390.625`, -0.06257`}, {391.25`, -0.06007`}, {391.875`, -0.05694`}, {392.5`, -0.05296`}, {393.125`, -0.04866`}, {393.75`, -0.044`}, {394.375`, -0.03906`}, {395.`, -0.03399`}, {395.625`, -0.02904`}, {396.25`, -0.02384`}, {396.875`, -0.01843`}, {397.5`, -0.01298`}, {398.125`, -0.0074`}, {398.75`, -0.0015`}, {399.375`, 0.00386`}, {400.`, 0.0065`}, {400.625`, 0.0055`}, {401.25`, 0.00137`}, {401.875`, -0.00405`}, {402.5`, -0.00755`}, {403.125`, -0.00696`}, {403.75`, -0.00269`}, {404.375`, 0.00328`}, {405.`, 0.00844`}, {405.625`, 0.01005`}, {406.25`, 0.00696`}, {406.875`, 0.00101`}, {407.5`, -0.00515`}, {408.125`, -0.009`}, {408.75`, -0.00883`}, {409.375`, -0.00442`}, {410.`, 0.0014`}, {410.625`, 0.00588`}, {411.25`, 0.00702`}, {411.875`, 0.00442`}, {412.5`, -0.00088`}, {413.125`, -0.00558`}, {413.75`, -0.00705`}, {414.375`, -0.00475`}, {415.`, 0.00035`}, {415.625`, 0.00605`}, {416.25`, 0.00927`}, {416.875`, 0.00802`}, {417.5`, 0.00325`}, {418.125`, -0.00313`}, {418.75`, -0.0084`}, {419.375`, -0.01003`}, {420.`, -0.00693`}, {420.625`, -0.00113`}, {421.25`, 0.00464`}, {421.875`, 0.00795`}, {422.5`, 0.00717`}, {423.125`, 0.00266`}, {423.75`, -0.00277`}, {424.375`, -0.00618`}, {425.`, -0.00623`}, {425.625`, -0.0027`}, {426.25`, 0.00281`}, {426.875`, 0.00718`}, {427.5`, 0.00794`}, {428.125`, 0.00486`}, {428.75`, -0.00081`}, {429.375`, -0.00686`}, {430.`, -0.00993`}, {430.625`, -0.00844`}, {431.25`, -0.00325`}, {431.875`, 0.0031`}, {432.5`, 0.00818`}, {433.125`, 0.00924`}, {433.75`, 0.00591`}, {434.375`, 0.00024`}, {435.`, -0.00482`}, {435.625`, -0.00729`}, {436.25`, -0.00583`}, {436.875`, -0.00106`}, {437.5`, 0.00402`}, {438.125`, 0.00682`}, {438.75`, 0.00602`}, {439.375`, 0.00186`}, {440.`, -0.00407`}, {440.625`, -0.00823`}, {441.25`, -0.00847`}, {441.875`, -0.00469`}, {442.5`, 0.0014`}, {443.125`, 0.00738`}, {443.75`, 0.01001`}, {444.375`, 0.00797`}, {445.`, 0.00265`}, {445.625`, -0.00353`}, {446.25`, -0.00801`}, {446.875`, -0.00859`}, {447.5`, -0.00489`}, {448.125`, 0.00065`}, {448.75`, 0.00535`}, {449.375`, 0.00717`}, {450.`, 0.00505`}, {450.625`, -0.00006`}, {451.25`, -0.00509`}, {451.875`, -0.00724`}, {452.5`, -0.00574`}, {453.125`, -0.00091`}, {453.75`, 0.00496`}, {454.375`, 0.00873`}, {455.`, 0.00819`}, {455.625`, 0.00402`}, {456.25`, -0.0022`}, {456.875`, -0.00781`}, {457.5`, -0.0099`}, {458.125`, -0.00737`}, {458.75`, -0.00177`}, {459.375`, 0.00427`}, {460.`, 0.00841`}, {460.625`, 0.00826`}, {461.25`, 0.00411`}, {461.875`, -0.00167`}, {462.5`, -0.00596`}, {463.125`, -0.0072`}, {463.75`, -0.00441`}, {464.375`, 0.00087`}, {465.`, 0.00559`}, {465.625`, 0.00716`}, {466.25`, 0.0051`}, {466.875`, 0.00016`}, {467.5`, -0.00553`}, {468.125`, -0.00866`}, {468.75`, -0.00763`}, {469.375`, -0.00299`}, {470.`, 0.00321`}, {470.625`, 0.00848`}, {471.25`, 0.00981`}, {471.875`, 0.00651`}, {472.5`, 0.00048`}, {473.125`, -0.00553`}, {473.75`, -0.00898`}, {474.375`, -0.00809`}, {475.`, -0.00323`}, {475.625`, 0.00254`}, {476.25`, 0.00662`}, {476.875`, 0.00725`}, {477.5`, 0.00418`}, {478.125`, -0.00122`}, {478.75`, -0.00567`}, {479.375`, -0.00692`}};
```

And the image I used in the background (backimage.jpg) is
[image]

After running this command in the Mathematica notebook, this is how it looks in the working environment:
[image]

Which is very nice and it is exactly what I need. But when I try to export this graph (including the background) to pdf, this is what I get:
[image]

which is not the same as what I expected. I tried to use `PrintingStyleEnvironment` to sort this issue out, but it was not successful.

Comment: Please provide detailed code how did you add the background image to the plot.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov he provided the code for that

Comment: I get the same happening with 8.0.4 on OS X. It seems the scaled on the image is forgotten during the export. Also tried exporting some of the examples in the docs and got the same problem

Comment: There's no problem on WinXp,

Comment: Just wanted to mention that my version number is 8.0.4.0 and platform is Microsoft Windows 7 (64-bit).

Comment: Need "backimage.jpg" also that you are importing.

Comment: @Nasser I did not get what you exactly mean. But if you need "backimage.jpg" which is imported in the code as the background, it is the first image of the post, as it is mentioned and provided above.

Comment: The command I used to export the plot to pdf was `Export`. It did not work for me.

Comment: No problems here - Mathematica version 9, Mac OS X version 10.9.